# Get Instagram access token without login screen

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm working with the new Instagram api in my website. The code-behind is c#.
I need to retrieve photos with a given hashtag and then to show that photos in my web pages.

Is it possible to do that without show a login screen for every user that visit my web app to get the access token?

I can see every tag that I want in public instagram pages without autenticate myself (Es: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/ciao/).

If the answer is negative can i authenticate myself via api and avoid the login screen?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Instagram API docs:

> You can retrieve photos with a given hashtag by accessing the following URL with your `access_token` (replace `ACCESS-TOKEN` with your own):
>
> ```
> https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
> ```
>
> The Instagram API requires an `access_token` from authenticated users for each endpoint. We no longer support making requests using just the `client_id`.

This `access_token` does not need to be your user's token. It could be your token instead. But it has to be somebody's.

Just make sure to review the [rate limit](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/) documentation also. Rate limits are separate for each access token, so you may need to generate a number of access tokens and round-robin them. You could also allow your users to login if they want, and use their access token if they're logged in.

Comment: But how can i get/provide the access token? Do i login once and use that access token for my website/app for forever?
How is that safe? Or do i renew the token by hand every once in a while? This all sounds like hacky solutions and like instagram simply does not want you to display their data on any website :-(

Comment: This is exactly what I mean. I know that instagram has endpoints to retrieve photos that require the access token, but how can I get the access token without login using the login screen? (Even if it's me or someone else). I only want to display photos on my website, nothing else. I can't believe that Instagram do not provide a simple api without authenticate everytime I need to display photos with an hashtag.

Comment: You have to generate an `access_token` by logging in as a specific user. You can store the tokens for later use, but there is no way around generating them at all.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN',
    hashtag='vindiesel', // hashtag without # symbol
    num_photos = 4;

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + hashtag + '/media/recent',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        for(x in data.data){
            $('ul').append('<li><img src="'+data.data[x].images.standard_resolution.url+'"></li>');  
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});

</script>
```